# How to Add Collection List to a List in Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, list

I am Executing two  linq queries for employees and contractors in a method and Converting to List then i am bind to list seperately declared in the model class.

I am executing this method every time for each company from list of companies by passing company id and model class as parameters like

```
    public void GetEmployeeContractorsTimesheetNotEntered(int COMP_ID, string COMPANY_NAME, TimesheetModel model)
    {
        context = new ResLandEntities();
        DateTime todayDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
        DateTime thisWeekStartDate = todayDate.AddDays(-(int)todayDate.DayOfWeek).Date; //Start Date of Current Week
        DateTime thisWeekEndDate = thisWeekStartDate.AddDays(6); // End Date of Current Week
        var todaysDay = (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;


        var employeesNotEnteredTimesheetList = (from emps in context.EMPLOYEE
                                                join comp in context.COMPANY on emps.COMP_ID equals comp.ID
                                                join notify in context.NOTIFICATION on emps.NOTIFICATION_ID equals notify.ID
                                                from week in context.WEEK_CALENDER
                                                from statlk in context.STATUS_LKUP
                                                where !context.TIMESHEET.Any(m => m.WEEK_CAL_ID == week.ID 
                                                    && m.RES_TYPE == "EMPLOYEE" 
                                                    && m.RES_ID == emps.ID
                                                    && m.COMP_ID == COMP_ID
                                                    && m.IS_DELETED=="N") &&
                                                week.WEEK_START_DT.Month == DateTime.Now.Month &&
                                                week.WEEK_START_DT.Year == DateTime.Now.Year &&
                                                week.WEEK_END_DT<=thisWeekEndDate &&
                                                statlk.TYPE == "TIMESHEET" &&
                                                statlk.STATE == "NOT_ENTERED" &&
                                                emps.IS_DELETED == "N" &&
                                                emps.COMP_ID==COMP_ID
                                                select new TimesheetModel
                                                {
                                                    EMP_ID = emps.ID,
                                                    EMP_COMP_ID = emps.COMP_EMP_ID,
                                                    EMPLOYEE_NAME = emps.FIRST_NAME + " " + emps.LAST_NAME,
                                                    COMPANY_NAME = comp.NAME,
                                                    PrimaryEmail = notify.PRI_EMAIL_ID,
                                                    SDate = week.WEEK_START_DT,
                                                    EDate = week.WEEK_END_DT,
                                                    EMP_STATUS = "NOT_ENTERED"
                                                }).Distinct().ToList();

         //Adding a Collection of List Here
        model.GetTimesheetNotEnteredDetails.AddRange(employeesNotEnteredTimesheetList.GroupBy(m => m.EMP_ID).Select(m => m.First()).ToList());

        var contractorsNotEnteredTimesheetList = (from contrs in context.CONTRACTOR
                                                  join client in context.CLIENT on contrs.CLIENT_ID equals client.ID
                                                  join notification in context.NOTIFICATION on contrs.NOTIFICATION_ID equals notification.ID
                                                  from week in context.WEEK_CALENDER
                                                  from statlk in context.STATUS_LKUP
                                                  where !context.TIMESHEET.Any(m => m.RES_ID == contrs.ID
                                                      && m.WEEK_CAL_ID == week.ID
                                                      && m.COMP_ID == COMP_ID
                                                      && m.RES_TYPE == "CONTRACTOR"
                                                      && m.IS_DELETED == "N")
                                                  && week.WEEK_START_DT.Month == DateTime.Now.Month
                                                  && week.WEEK_START_DT.Year == DateTime.Now.Year
                                                  && statlk.STATE == "NOT_ENTERED"
                                                  && statlk.TYPE == "TIMESHEET"
                                                  && contrs.IS_DELETED == "N"
                                                  && week.WEEK_START_DT <= thisWeekEndDate
                                                  && contrs.COMP_ID == COMP_ID
                                                  select new TimesheetModel
                                                  {
                                                      EMP_ID=contrs.ID,
                                                      EMPLOYEE_NAME = contrs.FIRST_NAME + " " + contrs.LAST_NAME,
                                                      COMPANY_NAME = COMPANY_NAME,
                                                      SDate=week.WEEK_START_DT,
                                                      EDate=week.WEEK_END_DT,
                                                      CLIENT_NAME = client.NAME,
                                                      PrimaryEmail = notification.PRI_EMAIL_ID
                                                  }).Distinct().ToList();

       //Adding Collection of List Here
        model.GetContractorNotEnteredDetails .AddRange(contractorsNotEnteredTimesheetList.GroupBy(m => m.EMP_ID).Select(m => m.First()).ToList()); 


    }
```

Now, my problem is I want to add list collection separately to two list, though i am binding the list separately , the two results of employees and contractors  lists are clubbing in  two lists like employees and contractors are in binding the two lists instead it should bind separately. whats going wrong, is it "AddRange" should  not use for binding collection list to  one list, is there any way for this solution, please help me anyone.

Comment: No, i am adding different list, but same class type, is it a problem, is it should be different class types?

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
var props = typeof(TimesheetModel).GetProperties();

               DataTable dt= new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.AddRange(
                  props.Select(p => new DataColumn(p.Name, p.PropertyType)).ToArray()
                );

                employeesNotEnteredTimesheetList.ForEach(
                  i => dt.Rows.Add(props.Select(p => p.GetValue(i, null)).ToArray())
                );

 var list1 = (from p in dt.AsEnumerable()                         
                        select p).ToList();
```

//similar for second list

Comment: i need to get different results, as your above code, both the results in same list

Answer (score 1):

Finally Got it.

Just I have separated Accessors in different Classes like

```
 public class EmployeeTimesheetDetails
{
    public int EMP_ID { get; set; }
    public string EMP_COMP_ID { get; set; }
    public string EMPLOYEE_NAME { get; set; }
    public string COMPANY_NAME { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryEmail { get; set; }
    public DateTime SDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EDate { get; set; }
    public string EMP_STATUS { get; set; }
}
public class ContractorsTimesheetDetails
{
    public int CONTR_ID { get; set; }
    public string CONTRACTOR_NAME { get; set; }
    public string COMPANY_NAME { get; set; }
    public DateTime SDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EDate { get; set; }
    public string CLIENT_NAME { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryEmail { get; set; }
}
```

and modified the two list in model class like

```
    public List<EmployeeTimesheetDetails> GetTimesheetNotEnteredDetails { get;  set;}

    public List<ContractorsTimesheetDetails> GetContractorNotEnteredDetails { get; set; }
```

This modification is cleared my issue .

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two properties in the class `TimesheetModel`, something like this:

```
public class CompanyListModel
{
     public List<CompanyModel> CompanyList { get; set; };
}

public class CompanyModel 
{
        public List<TimesheetModel > EmployeesNotEnteredTimesheetList { get; set; };

        public List<TimesheetModel > ContractorsNotEnteredTimesheetList { get; set; };
}
```

Then add like this:

```
 public void GetEmployeeContractorsTimesheetNotEntered(int COMP_ID, string COMPANY_NAME, CompanyListModel model)
  {
     // your stuff
     CompanyModel conpanyModel = new CompanyModel();

     conpanyModel.EmployeesNotEnteredTimesheetList  = employeesNotEnteredTimesheetList.GroupBy(m => m.EMP_ID).Select(m => m.First()).ToList();

     conpanyModel.ContractorsNotEnteredTimesheetList = contractorsNotEnteredTimesheetList.GroupBy(m => m.EMP_ID).Select(m => m.First()).ToList(); 

     model.CompanyList.add(companyModel);
     // your stuff
}
```

Comment: Yes, But I have written the two lists with same Class Type like public List<TimesheetModel> EmployeeNotEnteredTimesheetList{get;set;}                     public List<TimesheetModel>  ContractorsTimesheetList{get;set;}

Comment: Yes, same I Have done with separate list like your code, just name difference.

Comment: So where is the issue now? Don't use addRange, it just append the list to the other.

Comment: The issue results are clubbing in the two lists instead of sepearte lists, do with problem same object type?

Comment: @sanjay You should need something like what in the updatded post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61268/discussion-between-amanvirdi-and-sanjay).